# How to publish Platform Event from aiosfstream python library?

Tags: python, platform-event, cometd

I'm trying to consume/publish Platform Events using **aiosfstream** python library.
There is a publish() function but I always get an error response:

```
aiocometd.exceptions.ServerError: ('Publish request failed.', {'clientId': '3bq174in63lwkx7j1asoyin32nemt', 'channel': '/event/TestEvent__e', 'id': '4', 'successful': False})
```

Here is my code to publish an event. TestEvent__e has just one text field in it - message__c.

```
CHANNEL_PATH = "/event/TestEvent__e"
messageData = {"message__c": "Hello, THIS IS CLIENT SPEAKING!!"}
await client.publish(CHANNEL_PATH,message)
```

**What can I change? What would be the correct message format to publish it to salesforce event bus?**

**aiosfstream**:

- https://github.com/robertmrk/aiosfstream
- https://aiosfstream.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#aiosfstream.Client.publish

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm the author of [aiosfstream](https://github.com/robertmrk/aiosfstream). Thanks for notifying me about this question!

### tl;dr

You can use [aiosfstream](https://github.com/robertmrk/aiosfstream) to [subscribe and listen for platform events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_subscribe_cometd.htm), but you *can't* use it for publishing.

To publish platform events you have to use one of the documented methods. Since you're trying to publish events from a python application, [publishing events with the REST or SOAP API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_publish_api.htm) is what probably best suits your needs.

### Detailed explanation

Salesforce's Streaming API is implemented using a [CometD](https://cometd.org/) server with Salesforce's custom replay extension and authentication.
Similarly, [aiosfstream](https://github.com/robertmrk/aiosfstream) is based on [aiocometd](https://github.com/robertmrk/aiocometd), which is a CometD client.

With CometD you can listen for or stream incoming messages and you can also publish messages on certain channels. A good example to this is [CometD's chat example](http://aiocometd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#usage). So the implementation of the publish method in aiosfstream comes from the aiocometd library. However, while publishing messages is a legal and useful operation in other CometD applications in the case of the Streaming API it is a legal but a totally useless operation, since Salesforce rejects messages published on any channel (as far as I know). So in practice, you can transfer messages to Salesforce, but they'll be ignored.

Thanks for reporting this issue, it made me realize how misleading the presence of the publish method is!